# jQuery and couchdb: is it possible to handle "created" and "already exist" in one handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, couchdb

A typical pattern no use REST couchDB API is "create if not exist". For example, if i want to create a database if it's not exist:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: DB + 'mydatabase',
});
```

As a programmer, both `201 Created` and `412 Prerequisite failed` are success, since i want database to be in place and it's perfectly fine with me if it's just created or it was already here. But from `jQuery` perspective, `201` is success and `412` is a failure - so i need to write lots of code just to make sure that database is in place:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: DB + 'mydatabase',
}).fail( function( arg ) {
  if( 412 == arg.statusCode ) {
    // This is success.
  } else {
    //  This is failure.
  }
}).done( function( arg ) {
  //  This is another success.
});
```

This effectively makes code a mess with success in two places (even in two different callbacks!). Is it possible to somehow reduce error handling in a less code, preferably processing success in one place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively you can use the `statusCode` object to bind a shared event handler to *200* and *412*.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: DB + 'mydatabase',
    statusCode: {
        200: myHandler,
        412: myHandler
    }
});

function myHandler(data, statusText, jqXHR) {
    // do something with the data
}
```

For completeness here's the other way I described in my comment.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: DB + 'mydatabase',
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 200 || jqXHR.status === 412) {
            // do something
        }
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know jQuery supported this kind of option.

Comment: It's no difference with my code and requires success handler to be defined in two places. What i want is to write down success handler as anonymous function, without writing dozens of named one-liners for simple error and success handling.

Comment: Well, no there is no way to do that. I mean there's one more way but that'll require inspecting the status code and triggering different actions based on that.